# Stack Overflow doesn't highlight some tags (?)

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, question-lists

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but starting today I noticed SO stopped highlighting the `c#` and `c++` tags for some unknown reason, even though they're selected as "watched" (see the right side):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Nope, and it's not just that post, it's every single C++ and C# questions that get ignored

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917250/c-sharp-convert-comma-separated-string-to-dynamic-type for example has only the C# tag and it still doesn't show highlighted. It's making me believe the tag parser dies because of the non-alpha-numeric tag text (`#` and `++` specifically).

Comment: Ironically I just started listening to the SO podcast, from the beginning, and Joel just mentioned breaking the `C++` tag every other day because the `+` is technically a space when URL encoded. Well good, we agree, it's broken -- do I need to do anything else? Like is there an "issues" list somewhere where I can file the bug? Or is this enough?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We had a change go out that involved regenerating a bunch of javascript from typescript. Turned out that one of the typescript files was ANSI-encoded and that broke special character handling in tag names.

Fixing the file encoding gives us this fun .ts diff:

[image]

that becomes more clear in the .js version:

[image]

The fix is live in production. Thanks for the report!

Comment: This explains why the same was happening to `.net` as well, it's exactly those 3 characters between `c++`, `c#` and `.net` lol

Comment: Oh dear. I would never be brave enough to dump characters outside of ANSI in my source code files. Use Unicode escape sequences.